# Interactive commands discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**I have a bot that logs when invites are being created and the standard channel where the logs are going are only going to appear in the server / channel ID I placed there. I want to be able to change this per server it is in.**

**Output** (What I am trying to achieve)

User: !log channel (CHANNEL ID)

Bot: `New log channel set.`  (The logs will now log into the channel ID set, since the bot will be in a numerous amount of servers, I want it to only take affect if the channel ID matches the guild the command is being invoked in)

> I want Server Owners and Administrators to be able to change the channel ID without accessing the VSC, how would I make it so anyone can change it outside of the VSC.

**Notice**: I want to be able to use this information and knowledge for another commands and features I am developing. If anyone knows a correct term for what I am trying to do here please let me know and I appreciate all the help. (I'm just looking for a term or a reference on how to do things like this, I'm not asking for the code)

Comment: You can use args? `msg.content.split(/ +/g)`

Comment: I was debating about using args but thanks I'll try using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you *can* use classic message arguments as pointed out in the comments, I suggest you to use Discord's new **slash commands** feature. They allow for tight integration with Discord's clients and provides a much nicer user experience (autocomplete helps users with arguments).

[image: why slash commands should be used]

However, discord.js v12 does not officially support slash commands (v13 does). You could:

- use an external library: [/create](https://slash-create.js.org/#/) or
- install v13-dev or
- wait until v13 is released (not really suitable).

Edit: v13 has been released, and slash commands are now heavily recommended, with Discord now requiring verified bots to use them.

Comment: Slash commands are actually here! You can get the event with `client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', interaction => {})`